# Spacing in bibliography

Tags: spacing, bibliographies

I would like to ask for help regarding writting bibliography. In bibliography section the Latex compiler puts huge gaps between the words. I would be grateful if someone could tell me how to get rid off them.

The code:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem{tesla}
    \emph{Model S $\mid$ Tesla}.Tesla [online].[cit. 2017-04-29]. Dostupné z: https://www.tesla.com/models

\end{thebibliography}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hyphens]{url}

\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
    \bibitem{tesla}
    \emph{Model S $\mid$ Tesla}.Tesla [online].[cit. 2017-04-29]. Dostupné z: \url{https://www.tesla.com/models}

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]